# iAd integration in IPhone

Tags: iphone, testing, admob, iad, ads

I want to integrate iAd and adMob in My application. 
I have also integrate it successfully. when iAd in not able to load at that time adMob is come. adMob is working fine when I have test is using test Mode .

But when I have upload to appstore and download in my device It show me the iAd with **"Test Advertisement"** and not able to load adMob in device when test mode is off.

Can any one help me to find out solution of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you aren't using it already you should integrate adwhirl into your app, it will choose between iad and admob automatically. Now, just because you have requests being sent doesn't necessarily mean they are going to get filled, so admob won't always show. Also make sure that you have all the requirements for iad filled out on itunes connect, if you don't have taxes, etc filled out apple will not send you any ads.

Hope that answers your question, sorry I'm a little unclear as to what you're asking.

Comment: adWhirl doesn't support iPad though. That may be an issue.

Comment: Check out Google AdMob Mediation instead of adWhirl https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/ios/mediation