# iAds: Displaying own ads when didFailToReceiveAdWithError

Tags: ios, admob, iad, adwhirl

Outside the US and a few other countries (UK, France, Deutschland, Italia, España, Japan/日本), ads from the [iAd Network](http://advertising.apple.com/) aren't showing up much on iOS, yet.

In the meantime, besides using [AdMob](http://www.admob.com/) and [the like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5387609/iad-integration-in-iphone) to fill the blanks, I wonder if it's possible to display our own ads built with the [iAd Producer](http://developer.apple.com/iad/iadproducer/).

So, the mechanism would be that when advertisements are not available, therefore triggering `bannerView:didFailToReceiveAdWithError:`, it triggers our own ad instead.

If so, any ideas on: (1) if it's effectively possible to run our own iAd-Producer ads; (2) if so, how to implement that mechanism?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also create what adMob calls "In-house" ads. You can upload an image to use as the ad, or simply specify some text and a small icon and AdMob will make it look like their standard ads.  This way, you can have your house ads filling up the remaining inventory when iAds aren't being displayed (100% house ads), or whatever amount of space you would like.

I've built an [open-source library](https://github.com/larsacus/LARSAdController) to handle both iAds and fallback AdMob ads in a single container with a single line of code in each view.  This allows me to customize everything about my users' ad experience when there are no iAds to display.  Just set your google publisher id to your account's and you're good to go.

Comment: +1: thanks. Since the time I posted this question, I tried AdWhirl, which looked rather promising, but I had lots of issue with Location, which triggered crashes quite often. I decided to go with AdMob, which is very stable (so far) and overly easy to use. I'll try your code as it seems to be exactly what I want to do. Cheers.

Comment: not sure if you can answer this, but that'd help: is it possible to run your own iAds within your App, featuring your other iOS Apps? If so, should the ads be built-in in the App, or pulled/fetched from Apple?

Comment: The only way to run ads for your own apps with iAd is to actually buy ad space from apple, which often costs way more per user than you would make off of them. That's why I mentioned the house ads. They're free, they come with admob, and you can display them when there are no iAds to display. Another way to do it (albeit ,more work) would be to just make 320x50 png files and insert them into UIImageViews that display when there are no iAds to display. Then simply have them open an iTunes link when tapped. But unfortunately, there is no *free* way to run "house" ads through iAd.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [custom events](http://code.google.com/p/adwhirl/wiki/CustomEvents) in AdWhirl to basically make your iAd-Producer ads its own ad network, where you can assign it a percentage and backfill order.

You will have to implement the code to create the ad and replace the bannerView with your new ad.